# Создание парсеров на PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Хотелось бы узнать знание каких тем необходимо для создания парсеров на PHP.

Comment: Отвечу вопросом на вопрос: "Что может понадобится для приготовления бутерброда?"

Answer (score 3):

Ну для простых парсеров достаточно знать, что такое цикл for и
работа с регулярными выражениями (функции `preg_match`, `preg_match_all`).

Comment: Для более хитрых - curl...

Answer (score 3):

Нужно знание парсеров на PHP.
Ну или знание регулярок или простая логика (для посимвольного перебора).
А вы говорите о парсерах чего?

Answer (score 1):

1. Во-первых, необходимо знать HTML и DOM. Поиск информации в полученном коде HTML страницы без этого не возможен.
2. Во-вторых, без знания регулярок порой трудно обойтись.
   Разумеется Вы должны в необходимом объеме владеть PHP.

Затем, когда Вы начнете писать парсеры выяснится, что необходим curl. И для ускорения работы полезна многопоточность

Answer (score 0):

- pcntl_fork - запуск в многопоточном режиме
- curl - получение страниц, быстрее чем file_get_contents и можно самому задавать заголовки запроса, чтобы больше быть похожим на реального пользователя
- парсер html страницы типа nokogiri и регулярные выражения, чтобы получать нужные данные

Comment: Чушь, вся многопоточность в php, а без нее скорость - "0"...<br />
Сейчас учу python для этих целей...

Comment: Не согласен. Хоть и псевдо-, но все-таки, это параллельное выполнение. В случае с парсером это актуально, т.к. нужно быстро получить контент.

Comment: Память кушает очень прилично, если писать парсер с нуля то имхо лучше выполнить на языке который предназначен для многопоточности, ну а если уже есть готовый шаблон работающий в один поток, то можно и на php оставить...